# Sort a list according to the indexes of a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to make the elements entered in a list have the same index as those of a given word?

In this case it is a mystery word chosen at random in a game of hangman.

It could look like this (that's just a code portion that I take but the problem is right here):

```py
import random
    
WORDS = ('Fire', 'Wind', 'Water', 'Earth')
word = random.choice(WORDS)
letters = []
    
while len(letter) != len(word):
    aletter = input('choose a letter...') 
    if aletter in word and len(aletter) == 1:
        for i in range(len(word)):
            letter.append(aletter)
```

I don't know how to say that each element added to the list will not be put in disorder but will be put in order even if we type it before the first letter in the input `aletter`.

For example if the word is Wind and I send 'i' (which is in the word) before 'W', but I enter 'W' after it then 'i' will be appended before 'W' instead of ['W', 'i'] (The normal order would be ['W', 'i', 'n', 'd'] but with this problem the letters could be totally reversed depending on the order they are appended. I figured it had something to do with the index of the elements.

So here's what I tried to say in a way:

"This list (`letters`) will rearrange itself according to the indexes of the elements in `word`."

`letters[i] = word[k]`

This example above is with a double loop, one for `aletter` and one for `word`, the indexes are `i` and `k`.

`letters.insert(i, aletter)`

In this one I want to insert all `aletter` in index of `word`, at the position `i`.

`letters.index(aletter) == i`

And finally in this one I want each index of the entered elements to be equal to those of `word`.

I converted the list in a string to compare them, but my problem is how to sort this list first.

Comment: Maybe show us one example input and the expected output.

Comment: the expected output would be to have the word Wind for example (only if it's the randomly chosen word of course) and well when I type an 'n' or a 'd' before the W instead of being added at the beginning it will be added at the end when I enter W in list

The expected message would be :

Wind' even if I type i then n then d instead of 

indW with the above example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, you may want to use some placeholders, e.g. underscores, for the letters that have not been guessed yet. For example:

```py
import random

WORDS = ('Fire', 'Wind', 'Water', 'Earth')
word = random.choice(WORDS)
letters = ['_' for letter in word]

while '_' in letters:
    print(''.join(letters))
    aletter = input('choose a letter...') 
    if aletter in word and len(aletter) == 1:
        for i, c in enumerate(word):
            if aletter == c:
                letters[i] = c
```

Comment: Maybe It'll work I'll try it and give you a feedback

Comment: It displays the following error : letters[i] = c TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Comment: Looks like you have inadvertently converted `letters` to a string somewhere in your code. Make sure to initialize `letters` as a list, as shown above, and keep it as a list.

Comment: The error may occur because I have converted the list into a string but I have to. Because I need to compare the string word to the string letters

Comment: Ah, but you can do that without changing `letters`. You could even do it the other way round: `if letters == list(word): ...`

Comment: Okay thanks that's fixed but I got another problem and it's a bigger issue I think when we loop the word in the list is repeated  2 time. If I search "F" it's gonna say F is in word and add F to the list but F is added 2 times and its the same with every letters added ['F', 'i', 'r', 'e'  'F', 'i', 'r'] As you can see the word is found but repeated how I  fix that ?

Comment: Make sure to never append anything to the `letters` list. Just initialize it once, with the right length, and only change it through item assignment, as shown above.